# How to evaluate the conditional probability P(X | Y∩Z) given P(X), P(Y), P(Z), P(X|Y) and P(X|Z)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it possible to express P(X | Y∩Z) in terms of P(X), P(Y), P(Z), P(X|Y) and P(X|Z)?

I tried using Bayes' Theorem, which says `P(A|B)=(P(B|A)*P(A))/P(B)`, which gives,

```
P(X | Y∩Z)=(P(Y∩Z | X)*P(X))/P(Y∩Z)
```

Which in turn gives,

```
P(X | Y∩Z)=(P(Y∩Z | X)*P(X))/(P(Y|Z)*P(Z))
```

But I can't get any further. I can't get rid of that intersection from the right hand side.

**EDIT**: It is also assumed that Y and Z form the countable partition of X. So, P(Y|X)+P(Z|X)=1.

Comment: What have you tried before posting here? Have you written out how $\mathbb{P}(X \mid Y \cap Z)$, $\mathbb{P}(X \mid Y)$, $\mathbb{P}(X \mid  Z)$ look like?

Comment: Yeah. I edited the question to include that.

Comment: I don't think that you can get rid of $\mathbb{P}( X \cap Y \cap Z)$ without more given probabilities or some sort of independence given.

Comment: Are you given that $Y,Z$ are independent?

Comment: No, there's no information given about whether Y and Z are independent.

Comment: But I think that Y and Z should be independent. Assuming they are independent, how would you simplify it further?

Comment: @JimmyR. If Y and Z are independent events, can we say that `P(Y∩Z | X)=P(Y|X)*P(Z|X)`?

Comment: Be careful: if $X, Y, Z$ are **events** then some formulas make sense, but if they are **random variables** then not. If you are using the set operators of union or intersection then you are using sets... but random variables are not sets, they are functions. However events are sets.

Comment: @Masacroso Yeah, X, Y and Z are events in my case, and not random variables. I guess now, after the discussions here, the problem is reduced to this question: If Y and Z form the complete subspace of X, where Y and Z are independent events, then can we say that: (i) P(Y∩Z | X)=P(Y|X)*P(Z|X)? (ii) P(X | YUZ)=P(X|Y)+P(X|Z)?

Comment: @JKnecht Y and Z are said to form the complete countable partition of X if P(X) = P(X|Y)*P(Y) + P(X|Z)*P(Z).

Comment: @JKnecht That's right. In other words, if Y and Z form the complete countable partition of X, then `P(Y|X)+P(Z|X)=1`.

Comment: @Kristada673 Yes, you can say that.